# Setting TEXT values to null does not reduce disk space usage of MySQL table

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, innodb, diskspace, rds

I am trying to reduce the disk space usage of a table in an RDS instance of MySQL 5.6.23. It's an InnoDB table with about 8 million rows and 30 columns. Several of the columns are of type `TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL`. One of the reasons why the table is so big is because rather than deleting rows from this table, they are instead marked as deleted via a flag column named 'deleted'.

After reading the MySQL documentation on storage requirements:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html

It seems as though the storage required for a `TEXT` field depends on the length of text in the field rather than being a fixed size (`L + 2 bytes, where L < 2^16 and where L is the length of the value in bytes`). So although I've read elsewhere that these fields are in fact fixed width, I processed about 50,000 rows marked as deleted and set all their `TEXT` column values to null.

However, there was no reduction in disk space reported either by the MySQL client or the AWS Console RDS interface. Why didn't this free up disk space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set the column value to NULL InnoDB would have to reorganize the record storage in order to reduce the total amount of disk space used by the table. You should see a reduction if you a dummy ALTER TABLE that is not dummy enough for MySQL to notice a short-circuit way to do it making it actually rebuild the table, or manually drop, re-create, and reinsert the records. `OPTIMIZE TABLE` should do it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sasha's answer may or may not apply.

After setting the column to `NULL`, any freed blocks are made available for future `INSERTs` / `UPDATEs`.  But the freed blocks are not given back to the OS.  Whether a block is freed depends on a lot of details.

The amount of disk space for a `TEXT` field depends both on the amount of text and the Row_format ("Compact", etc).  A `TEXT` column may be entirely or partially stored in a block separate from the rest of the data.

If your table was created while `innodb_file_per_table` was `ON`, then `OPTIMIZE TABLE` will give the free space back to the OS.  And `SHOW TABLE STATUS` will show some decrease in values.

If `innodb_file_per_table` had been `OFF`, freed up space is left in `ibdata1`, but that file is not shrunken.  It can be shrunken only by dump all tables; stop mysqld; remove ibdata1; restart; reload.  (Yuck.)  `OPTIMIZE TABLE` will increase `Data_free` inside `ibdata1`.

(Assuming OFF) This will make the table more manageable, but leave a lot of free space in an un-shrunken `ibdata1`:

```
SET innodb_file_per_table = ON;
ALTER TABLE foo ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

If you anticipate growth in ibdata1 for other reasons; this may be wise to do.  Otherwise, it just makes the disk space problem worse.